# How can we prove this identify: $\int_0^{2\pi} \exp(i a\cos(x))\, dx = 2 \pi I_0(a)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

How can we argue that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \exp(i a\cos(x)) \,dx = 2 \pi I_0(a)
$$
where $I_0(a)$ is a modified Bessel function.

I tried simplifying it as below:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \exp(i a\cos(x))\, dx & = \int_0^\pi \exp(i a\cos(x))\, dx + \int_\pi^{2\pi} \exp(i a\cos(x))\, dx\\
& = \pi I_0(a) +  \int_0^\pi \exp(i a\cos(\theta + \pi))\, d\theta\\
& = \pi I_0(a) +  \int_0^\pi \exp(-i a\cos(\theta)) \, d\theta
\end{align}

How can I show that
$$
\int_0^\pi \exp(-i a\cos(\theta)) \, d\theta = \pi I_0(a) \text{ ?}
$$

Comment: The purpose of the $\exp$ notation is to avoid the need to use superscripts, since those can be cumbersome when the expression in the exponent takes a lot of space to write. Thus: $$ e^{-\frac 1 2 \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{x_i - \mu} \sigma \right)^2 } \quad\text{versus} \quad \exp \left( -\frac 1 2 \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{x_i - \mu} \sigma \right)^2 \right) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto 2\pi-x$, we see that

$$\int_\pi^{2\pi}e^{ia\cos(x)}\,dx=\int_0^\pi e^{ia\cos(x)}\,dx$$

Hence, we assert that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{ia\cos(x)}\,dx&=2\int_0^\pi e^{ia\cos(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=2\pi I_0(a)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!